# Transferable / URL export: Transfering bookmark data between Java App and Mozilla

Tags: java, firefox, mozilla, data-transfer, drag-and-drop

I'm writing a Java application and I want to integrate a feature to somewhat modify bookmark data from Mozilla. This sounds very complicated, but it's only a drag and drop issue:

1) I can't really drop more than one bookmark entry from Mozilla library to my Java application, because there are no DataFlavors available. Thus, obviously, I cannot read the raw data from the Transferable I get... Single entries come with 78 DataFlavors. Is there any way to enable multiple bookmark dropping?
I can circumvent this issue by exporting all bookmarks to HTML and importing it from inside my app, but it's not very pleasant.

2) It's also quite hard to figure out how to export any URL to Mozilla bookmarks. For instance, the best behaviour would be that Mozilla recognizes my data the same way it does with hyperlinks. Dropping a link, e.g. [Google](http://www.google.com), from inside the browser into the bookmark library immediately creates an entry with name "Google" and URL "http://www.google.com". My application though is forced to return an implementation of java.io.Reader because Mozilla Firefox library apparently doesn't accept anything else.

TL;DR: Is there any way (via drag and drop) so I can 1) import multiple bookmarks from Mozilla to Java App and 2) export any kind of Transferable data to Mozilla bookmarks library so both **name** and **URL** are directly recognized by Firefox?

I hope my question is clear.

Regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you dragging?  Since you mention multiple bookmarks, I take it you aren't dragging a hyperlink and you aren't dragging a bookmark item from the sidebar or toolbar.  Are you displaying Mozilla's bookmarks dialog window, selecting multiple rows in there, and dragging them onto your app?  When you say your application "is forced to return an implementation of java.io.Reader," what action on your part "forces" it to do that?  If it's a drag, what are the source and destination of that drag?

Comment: First, thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pressed <Enter>..
I have the bookmark window opened and if I drag multiple rows to my app, `DropTargetDropEvent#getCurrentDataFlavors()` returns 0.
If I want to export bookmarks, the method `Object getTransferData(...) {}` which holds the information has to return a `java.io.Reader` because otherwise a `ClassCastException` is thrown in my app when I hover the mouse over Mozilla bookmarks window saying it has to be `java.io.Reader`. If it is of type `java.io.Reader`, no exception is thrown, but I still cant drop it because of mismatching `DataFlavor` / data in general.

Comment: I've been playing around with this, and so far I've found that there is no way to accept the dragging of multiple bookmarks from Mozilla in any DataFlavor other than "text/uri-list", which is URIs without any bookmark names.

Comment: A Java application can receive both the name and URI of a *single* bookmark or link, by importing with a "text/html" flavor (though the characters seem to be strangely mis-encoded as UTF-16LE, no matter what Java thinks the encoding is).  But this doesn't seem to work in reverse:  I tried to export an identical HTML fragment (`<A HREF="...">Bookmark Name</A>`) using a "text/html" DataFlavor, but Mozilla won't accept it.  So I'm inclined to conclude that what you want to do cannot be done at this time.

Comment: Too bad... Thanks anyways for the help... I tried everything as well. :/

Comment: I also found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types#Dragging_Links) at developer.mozilla.org, but when I tried to have a Java component export using a `text/x-moz-url` DataFlavor, Mozilla allowed the drop but ignored it---no bookmark was added.

Comment: Okay, this helped a lot. I made some progress in my research, thank you very much!
My code right now: http://pastie.org/5602139
I noticed that "createTransferable" is called, while "getTransferData" never is... How does Firefox try to read the Data?
We cannot force Firefox to call "getTransferData"?
I also tried subclassing DataFlavor and overriding "getReaderForText" and replacing "java.lang.String" with "java.io.Reader" but that didn't work too, getReaderForText is never called either... What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of January 2013, on current versions of Java (7u10) / Firefox (17.0.1) for **Windows 7**, there doesn't seem a way to do what I want to.

Dragging multiple bookmarks into a Java Application comes without any DataFlavors, so reading from them is impossible.
Dropping a bookmark into Firefox seems impossible too - specifying only `text/x-moz-url` will make Firefox "accept" the data, but Firefox never attempts to read from it (the methods are never called). Specifying more than only `text/x-moz-url` (e.g. `text/x-moz-url; class=java.io.Reader`) leads to Firefox not accepting the Data at all.

Unless someone can provide a stable solution, this question is technically answered:

**It's not possible.**

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, I noticed that the type `text/x-moz-url` is not actually a text type at all, but a binary type.  It never has a charset associated with it;  it is always UTF-16LE.

The following works for me, at least in x86 Linux, but it does not work with the Windows version of Firefox at all:

```
static class Bookmark
implements Transferable {

    private final String mimeType;
    private final byte[] bytes;

    Bookmark(String uri,
             String name) {
        String text = uri + "\r\n" + name;
        this.bytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
        this.mimeType = "text/x-moz-url";
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        try {
            return new DataFlavor[] {
                new DataFlavor(mimeType + "; class=java.io.InputStream"),
                new DataFlavor(mimeType + "; class=java.nio.ByteBuffer"),
                new DataFlavor(mimeType + "; class=\"[B\""),
            };
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return flavor.isMimeTypeEqual(mimeType);
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
    throws IOException,
           UnsupportedFlavorException {

        Class<?> cls = flavor.getRepresentationClass();
        if (cls.equals(byte[].class)) {
            return bytes;
        }
        if (cls.equals(ByteBuffer.class)) {
            return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        }
        if (cls.equals(InputStream.class)) {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        }

        throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
    }
}
```

The reason it doesn't work in Windows is that the Windows version of Firefox apparently doesn't use `text/x-moz-url`.  When I drag a bookmark from Firefox and print out the supported DataFlavors, `text/x-moz-url` is not in the list at all.  Only string flavors (including `text/html` and `text/uri-list`), and a flavor whose representation class is java.net.URL, are supported, and none of those can hold the bookmark's name except `text/html`, which as I mentioned above, seems to be a type Firefox can provide but will not accept.

Comment: The Windows version does use `text/x-moz-url`. If the DataFlavor is `text/x-moz-url` with no representation class specified whatsoever, Firefox will accept your drop but ignore the data flow, somehow. No call on `getTransferData` is made and no call on `getReaderForText` is made. That's what I originally meant. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: When I say Windows doesn't support text/x-moz-url, I mean that I made a TransferHandler which prints out all the DataFlavors in its canImport method, and I dragged a bookmark from Firefox onto my JComponent.  In Linux, that printed list includes text/x-moz-url, but in Windows it does not.  That said, you're right that Windows Firefox seems to respond to a drag whose DataFlavor is text/x-moz-url while ignoring the actual drop.  I think that means the data isn't in the right format, possibly a charset issue.

Comment: I tried almost every charset, but whenever I enter something else than `text/x-moz-url`, the cursor turns "red" (firefox blocks it). However, with the blocking cursor, `getTransferData` is called several times, with the accepting cursor, it never is. It doesn't make any sense. I guess it's not possible with the current versions.